# Upgrading from Laravel 5.7 to 5.8 returns error: Class blade.compiler does not exist.... post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

I am trying to upgrade from [Laravel](https://Laravel.com) **5.7** to **5.8** but on running `composer update` the error below is returned. All related questions asked before do not have an answer that is working.

```
Class blade.compiler does not exist
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a custom blade directive in the **`register()`** method of **`/App/Providers/AppServiceProvider`**. Custom Blade directives need to be in the boot() method instead as explained on [Laracast discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/upgrade-to-58-class-bladecompiler-does-not-exist)